# python which of this two ways of getting set from list is better in terms of efficiency?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set

python which of this two ways of getting set from list  is better in term of efficiency?

a) `set([1,2,3])`

b) `{s for s in [1,2,3]}`

True to be told, the second way looks for me a bit weird anyway.

Following hint of `falsetru` I have tried:

```
andi$ python -m timeit '{s for s in [1,2,3]}'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.619 usec per loop
andi$ python -m timeit 'set(s for s in [1,2,3])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.911 usec per loop
```

and I obtained better results for construction with `{}`. The construction with `set([])` performed better only when passed the array directly without any list comprehensions.

[image]

Obtained results were better for `{}` both on OS X as well as on some EC2 Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

[`Timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) them:

```
In [1]: timeit set([1,2,3])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 359 ns per loop

In [2]: timeit {s for s in [1,2,3]}
1000000 loops, best of 3: 474 ns per loop
```

According to the above result, passing a list object to `set` is more efficient.

Comment: @falstru Thanks for pointing out `timeit` This is cool stuff!

Comment: @andi, Really? Which Python/platform do you use? Above results came from Python 2.7.8 64 bit + Windows 7 bit bit.

Comment: Python 2.7.6. Both in 32 and 64 bit mode I obtained better results for version with `{}`

Comment: @andi, I got similar result in Python 2.7.6/Ubuntu 14.04: 270 ns for `set(list)` / 429 ns for set comprehension.